# Can a redis instance subscribe to other redis instance?

Tags: laravel, redis, push-notification

I have a laravel with a redis instance on the local server.
I have another laravel server with redis instance on the web.

My local server needs to listen to the change in web server in the real-time matter. (like push notification from web server)

Since php don't have background service. I'm wondering is it possible for the local redis instance subscribe to web redis instance and get the notification?

Comment: Well the issue would be that your local dev server would have no way of connecting to a private IP in the web server without some tunnel trickery. What are you trying to accomplish through that sort of connection? Maybe there is a better way of accomplishing the end goal :)

Comment: I'm developing an ordering system for restaurant. To ensure system still usable when internet down, I have a local production server in restaurant. However, there's use case where customer can order remotely through our web server. What I need to accomplish is real time synchronization between local production server and web server.

Comment: Maybe this is of help: https://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: Thanks, but actually 2 different are handling different data, I just wish to utilize the SUB and PUB feature between 2 redis instance for event passing.